Send SSH input when output string is detected on windows from python
My company requires a passcode when SSHing to a server:
ssh myserver
Enter a passcode or select one of the following options:

Passcode:

I want call SSH in the background from a GUI so want to detect when a passcode is requested and prompt the user, then pass the passcode to SSH.
I've tried Paramiko, but we have a super complicated cert process that would require a lot of custom code (I've tried).  I've also tried pexpect.popen_spawn with no luck.
Is there any way to capture ssh output/supply ssh with input on windows + python?
